# macports issue for local portfile

Tags: macos, macports

I have got my files from here: https://trac.macports.org/browser/trunk/dports/devel/subversion?rev=80777
 - placed them under a similar folder tree, cd'ed into there and ran

```
gigi-kents-system-product-name:subversion 1.6.17 macport  kellogs$ sudo port install
Can't map the URL 'file://.' to a port description file ("Could not find Portfile in /Users/kellogs/subversion 1.6.17 macport ").
Please verify that the directory and portfile syntax are correct.
To use the current port, you must be in a port's directory.
```

I would have expected for the portfile's syntax to be correct actually.

What's up with that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is you didn't properly donwload the files, I just reproduced what you said and it works.

If you're downloading via browser remember to use the *Original format* links {[1](https://trac.macports.org/export/80777/trunk/dports/devel/subversion/Portfile), [2](https://trac.macports.org/export/80777/trunk/dports/devel/subversion/files/patch-path.c.diff), [3](https://trac.macports.org/export/80777/trunk/dports/devel/subversion/files/patch-Makefile.in.diff)} on bottom of each file's page.

Those spaces in folder name will give you issues anyway, seems the path isn't sanitized when running port.

If you're using **svn** instead checkout the port in a folder without spaces in its name.

```
svn co http://svn.macports.org/repository/macports/trunk/dports/devel/subversion/ mp-svn_1.6.17
```